# How to detect an exist element in an array with one or more elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/u53191Ln/48/)
It's a simple form to create a new form : label and it's input
I already did four validations :

1. if input is empty
2. if there in no label before adding an input
3. if the input id is not matched the label

But there is a new problem : if I enter an input id which already exist, it will add a second input for the same label,
For example :
[image]
I created two labels and their inputs
[image]
if I enter "a" in "input id" again, it will add a second input to label "a"
[image]
And if I add a same label again, then for adding the input is the same problem, it will add to both of them.
To avoid this problem, I think that I need to check : **if the input value is matched any existing input id, so don't add the input, the same for label**
I try to do this :

1. create an empty array
   `var inputExist = [];`
2. push the id in this array every time I add an new input `inputExist.push($('#input_id').val());`
3. do a loop `for` in the `else` to detect if the input value matched any element in the array
   `for (var i = 0; i < inputExist.length; i++){

     if($('#input_id').val() == inputExist[i]){}

   }`
   Scince the `if` condiction is based on the loop, I have to put the `if` inside the loop, which means the `else` too, so that will cause the adding input order do `array.length` times, not good!
   I have no idea how to separer the detection and the instruction followed.
   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array where you store the labels you already added (or the values);

```
var labelsArray = [];
var valuesArray = [];
```

Then when you handle the button click, add the following check:

```
var currentLabel = $('#lable_name').val();
if(labelsArray.indexOf(currentLabel) > -1){
    return;
}
```

In alternative you can use the jQuery function:

```
$.inArray(currentLabel, labelsArray)
```

Do the same with the values and you will be able to avoid duplication.

In alternative you can use jQuery to search for an input